# Hacer que el último evento escrito en un textarea sea el ejecutado

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, azure

No se si me hago entender con esto pero estoy tratando de que lo último escrito en un campo textarea o input sea el ejecutado para ser traducido en la api de azure traslator esto lo hago con ajax y laravel dejo colgado el código y puedan ayudarme.

Con el código jquey cuando escribo en el campo **textarea** se ejecuta el evento **each** a la vez verifico si el **textarea** no esta vació por espacios, este a su vez realiza el **ajax** pero si este tiene un retardo en la primera letra escrita y la ultima se ejecuta rápidamente **ejemplo:** h la primera ejecutada hola lo ultimo escrito la primera tuvo un retardo y la ultima se ejecuto rápidamente pero la primera que fue la h se ejecuto luego y en vez de traducir hola me traduce la h.

¿No hay forma de que lo último escrito sea ejecutado?

```
<textarea id="translate_q" name="q" maxlength="5000" rows="9" cols="100" placeholder="comienza a escribir" style="height: 159px">{{ $text  or ''}}</textarea>
```

e allí donde se ejecuta el código jquery

```
$('#translate_q').each(function(){
        var keyed = $('#translate_q').val().replace(/[\n]/g,'<br />');
        if(keyed){
            var langfrom = document.getElementById("translate_source").value;
            var langto = document.getElementById("translate_target").value;
            var textfrom = document.getElementById("translate_q").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8899-1",
                url: "/translator",
                data: {
                    langfrom: langfrom,
                    langto: langto,
                    textfrom: keyed
                },
            }).done(function(data) {
                // body...
                document.getElementById("translate_result").value = data;
                $("#action_copy").removeClass("off")
                $("#action_link").removeClass("off")
                $("#action_email").removeClass("off")
                $("#action_listen").removeClass("off")
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Para no tener problemas lo mejor seria hacerlo con un botón, si lo tienes que hacer así, le podrías poner un setTimeout de un par de segundos y si se pulsa una tecla antes de que salte el setTimeout lo borre y lo vuelva a setear.

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo del codigo alli puesto @Christian lo que pasa es que tengo que realizarlo asi de ese modo tal cual como esta alli solo que el codigo arriba da el problema ya mencionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar esto, que es como te decía en los comentarios:

```
const textarea = $('#test');
let id = false;
textarea.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(id) {
    window.clearTimeout(id);
  }

    id = setTimeout(function() {
      sendToApi();
    },1000);

});


function sendToApi()
{
    console.log($('#test').val());
}
```

Puedes usar el evento on change de jquery del textarea:

```
const textarea = $('#test');

textarea.on('change', function(e) {
     sendToApi();
});

function sendToApi()
{
    console.log('send');
}
```

Con esto cuando el focus salga del textarea se ejecutará el evento change del textarea.

Comment: No me funciona ya que debo hacer click fuera del textarea para que se ejecute

Comment: @vdjkelly Te actualizo la respuesta, saludos